# Conda installation not working (Traceback error)

Tags: python, path, windows-10, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install `astroquery` library using the command `conda install -c astropy astroquery` on the windows command prompt (I have Anaconda 3 on my path). But when I run the command, it gives me an TypeError. How do I fix this?

Edit - This is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1062, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 84, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 80, in do_call
    module = import_module(relative_mod, __name__.rsplit('.', 1)[0])
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_install.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .install import install
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import calculate_channel_urls, get_index
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 3, in <module>
    from libarchive.exception import ArchiveError as _LibarchiveArchiveError
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 48, in <module>
    libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 150, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1354, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1065, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1109, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1120, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1190, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from conda_package_handling.api import InvalidArchiveError
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\api.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .tarball import CondaTarBZ2 as _CondaTarBZ2
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda_package_handling\tarball.py", line 7, in <module>
    import libarchive
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .entry import ArchiveEntry
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\entry.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import ffi
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\libarchive\ffi.py", line 48, in <module>
    libarchive = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(libarchive_path)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None
```

(I needed to add more words to be able to post this so... blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah )

Comment: please post the full error traceback (copy paste it from your command prompt)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, it worked when I installed it using `Anaconda prompt` instead of `windows command prompt`. Thanks to the internet.